# Is there any way to bypass damaged display on a laptop and turn it on without connecting the display connector?

Tags: laptop, display

I have Lenovo Laptop Y7070 whose display lid broke.

So I tried to switch it on after unplugging the display connector from the laptop's motherboard, but it wont turn on.

And when I connected it back it turns on.

Is there any way to bypass this and turn the laptop on without connecting the display connector?

Comment: It must not be *just* a display connector. It must also have the power switch or something running over the same cable. Unplugging just the display would not prevent it from powering on. You could set the laptop to power on automatically in the BIOS under certain conditions - like a schedule, after power loss, or with a wake on lan packet.

Comment: thanks @Appleoddity will try that one out